# Memory management error in openpicus

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, porting

There is a code that was written for a linux environment which I am porting to an embedded board called openpicus which uses Microchip C30 complier. The problem is in the memory management section. 
The original code uses `malloc`and `free` functions. So the equivalent code for this platform is using FreeRTOS functions `pvPortMalloc`and `vPortFree`. When compiling i am getting the error from the compiler

> Error: A heap is required, but has not been specified

What should i do ? How to allocate memory.

Comment: Have directory name `FreeRTOS_MemMang`? If there then any heap management algorithm is theere? Can you post `FreeRTOSConfig.h` content? Also how you configure your target board chip RAM to use?

Comment: I think it uses `heap_2` algorithm for heap management. I use the IDE provided by them to configure and upload the code.